# Animating a block of HTML on scroll

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, animation, plugin

I'm pretty new to client side scripting and I'm still learning.

I've written this JS plugin which animates blocks of HTML (fade-in from left/top/right/bottom) as you scroll down the page.

Everything seems to be works correctly, but was just wondering if there is anyone who could suggest how I can improve on this...

For instance:

- Reduce the size of the code.
- Structure the plugin better.
- Stop repetitious code.
- Increase browser compatibility.
- Make better use of Jquery keywords.

Really just doing the same thing but written better!

**CSS:**

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.animate {
    position: relative;
}

.bg-info {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="animate bg-info" data-animation="left" data-distance="200" data-speed="1000" data-delay="0" data-offset="80" data-easing="easeInOutBack">Nulla vel varius dolor. In pellentesque mi ac congue pulvinar. Sed cursus tincidunt condimentum. Curabitur vel velit leo. Nulla condimentum dolor dui, nec convallis elit congue eu.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="animate bg-info" data-animation="top" data-distance="200" data-speed="1000" data-delay="500" data-offset="80" data-easing="easeInOutBack">Nulla vel varius dolor. In pellentesque mi ac congue pulvinar. Sed cursus tincidunt condimentum. Curabitur vel velit leo. Nulla condimentum dolor dui, nec convallis elit congue eu.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="animate bg-info" data-animation="bottom" data-distance="200" data-speed="1000" data-delay="1000" data-offset="80" data-easing="easeInOutBack">Nulla vel varius dolor. In pellentesque mi ac congue pulvinar. Sed cursus tincidunt condimentum. Curabitur vel velit leo. Nulla condimentum dolor dui, nec convallis elit congue eu.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="animate bg-info" data-animation="right" data-distance="200" data-speed="1000" data-delay="1500" data-offset="80" data-easing="easeInOutBack">Nulla vel varius dolor. In pellentesque mi ac congue pulvinar. Sed cursus tincidunt condimentum. Curabitur vel velit leo. Nulla condimentum dolor dui, nec convallis elit congue eu.</div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $.fn.animateSliders = function(options) {
        var style = { opacity: "0", "-ms-opacity": "0" };
        var settings = $.extend({
            offset: 80,
            distance : 200,
            animation: "left",
            easing: "easeInOutBack",
            speed: 1000,
            delay: 0
        }, options);

        $(".animate").each(function () {
            loadvalues($(this));
            if (settings.animation == 'left') {
                $(this).css({ left: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
            }
            if (settings.animation == 'top') {
                $(this).css({ top: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
            }
            if (settings.animation == 'right') {
                $(this).css({ right: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
            }
            if (settings.animation == 'bottom') {
                $(this).css({ bottom: -settings.distance + 'px' }).css(style);
            }
        });

        $(window).on("scroll load", function() {
            $(".animate").each(function () {
                loadvalues($(this)); 
                var i = parseFloat(settings.offset) / 100;
                var trigger = $(window).height() * i + $(window).scrollTop();
                var position = $(this).offset().top;

                if (settings.animation == 'bottom') {
                    position = position - settings.distance;
                }
                if (settings.animation == 'top') {
                    position = position + settings.distance;
                }

                if (position < trigger) {
                    if (settings.animation == 'left') {
                        $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'left': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
                    }
                    if (settings.animation == 'top') {
                        $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'top': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
                    }
                    if (settings.animation == 'right') {
                        $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'right': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
                    }
                    if (settings.animation == 'bottom') {
                        $(this).delay(settings.delay).animate({ 'bottom': '0px', opacity: 1 }, settings.speed, settings.easing);
                    }
                };
            });
        });

        function loadvalues(obj) {
            if (obj.attr('data-animation')) {
                settings.animation = obj.data("animation");
            };

            if (obj.attr('data-offset')) {
                settings.offset = obj.data("offset");
            };

            if (obj.attr('data-distance')) {
                settings.distance = obj.data("distance");
            };

            if (obj.attr('data-easing')) {
                settings.easing = obj.data("easing");
            };

            if (obj.attr('data-speed')) {
                settings.speed = obj.data("speed");
            };

            if (obj.attr('data-delay')) {
                settings.delay = obj.data("delay");
            };
        }
    };
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.animateSliders({offset : 200});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

When you have multiple conditions on the same value, then you should chain the conditions using `else if`. For example in most in most of the conditions on `settings. animation`.

Also, since your checks on `settings.animation` are highly repetitive for left, right, top, bottom, it would be better to rewrite with a loop.

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> position = position + settings.distance;
> ```

It's more compact to write like this:

```
position += settings.distance;
```

---

Other than these minor issues, the code seems fine.

Answer (score 4):

**loadValues() is rather problematic.**

It checks for each possible data-attribute and if present overrides the value in `settings`. These repeated checks are just duplicated code which could be eliminated by just calling `.data()` without parameters to grab all the data-attributes. But the fact that it's modifying `settings` is a real problem because the function is used like so:

```
$(".animate").each(function () {
    loadvalues($(this));
    // ... animate based on settings ...
});
```

Now consider when there are two `.animate` elements on page:

```
<div class="animate" data-speed="200"></div>
<div class="animate" data-delay="1000"></div>
```

The first one will be animated with `speed=200` and default delay, but the second one will be animated with both `delay=1000` and `speed=200` because each time `loadValues()` is ran, the values it overrides in `settings` will stay there.

**This jQuery plugin is hard-coded to a concrete selector.**

Instead of selecting `.animate` class directly inside the plugin, you should use the `this` context element:

```
this.each(function () {
    ...
});
```

After that you can use the plugin to animate any element:

```
$(".animate, .some-other-class").animateSliders();
```